# Why is my Android Studio 2.3.3 not upgrading to Canary? Windows

Tags: android-studio, android-support-design, canary-deployment

Android Studio opens and asks me to upgrade to Canary and once it's downloaded and I have followed the prompts it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unpack the ZIP file.
2. Rename the resulting folder to something unique
   like "Android Studio Preview." 
   3.Move it to a permanent location, such
   as next to your existing Android Studio install in C:\Program
   Files\Android.
3. Inside C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
   Preview\bin\, launch studio64.exe (or if you're on a 32-bit machine,
   launch studio.exe).

**

### To make the preview version available in your Start menu, right-click studio64.exe and click Pin to Start Menu.

**
Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html